# How to draw line between 1 widget to 2nd widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a comment tree but I don't have any idea how to do that. The package I found on `pub.dev` is not like what I want. I mesh with codes. No tutorial found related to me.

This is what I want :

[image]

I want a tutorial or idea to create design like showing in the image.

Comment: Please, check this [Treeview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fancy_tree_view)!

Comment: It's really hard to understand this script for custom use. I'm looking, at how I can customize the script. If you have any solution to use this script as I want. I'm here to listen or read

Answer (score 0):

You can draw line like this

```
SizeBox(
height : 2,
width :  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
child : Container(color:Colors.black)
),
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
IntrinsicHeight(
child: Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
children: <Widget>[
  Container(width: 2.0, color:Colors.black),//(or use VerticalDivider())
  SizedBox(width: 4.0),
  YourCommentWidget(),
 ],
))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this package. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_fancy_tree_view

@Pradip said in comments.

If that you want, just add in pubspec.yaml file or you want to customize like in image just Copy the code from git repository and paste in your project as separate directory.

Edit as you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your tree, you can use divider() for clear line, also you can use sizedbox.

firstwidget (
child : secondwidget (child : ..............)
)

simply you can wrap second widget with a padding.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I achieve what I want. I think is not an Optimize way. I really like to know your comment on my code. It's litter meshy but the output looks nice.

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

    class TestTree extends StatelessWidget {
      const TestTree({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('title'),
            ),
            body: ListView(
              children: [
                commentTreeRoot(
                  context: context,
                  image:
                      'https://www.whatsappprofiledpimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/beaJKHutiful-girl-profile-p-199x300.jpg',
                  name: 'User Name',
                  subtitle: '11111 Comment Text User name Comment Text User name ',
                  posteDate: Text('20:18'),
                  content:
                      Text("""The :expressions will be suitable for girls, guys,\n
    married people too. Because in life complications start and\n
    ends with girls at the same time happiness comes to girls and only girls. Thus, even a silly waste paper will look bright when it is in the hands of beautiful girls.
    The pixels are picture perfect in our website."""),
                  comments: [
                    commentTreeChild(
                        context,
                        'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT16eO5W8VPjVFrkvG8n_2FQKjByMcbLtBF4A&usqp=CAU,',
                        [
                          commentTreeChild(
                              context,
                              'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT16eO5W8VPjVFrkvG8n_2FQKjByMcbLtBF4A&usqp=CAU',
                              [],
                              margin: 40,
                              last: true)
                        ]),
                    commentTreeChild(
                        context,
                        'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT16eO5W8VPjVFrkvG8n_2FQKjByMcbLtBF4A&usqp=CAU',
                        last: true,
                        []),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ));
      }

      Widget commentTreeRoot({
        required BuildContext context,
        required String image,
        required String name,
        required String subtitle,
        required Widget posteDate,
        required Widget content,
        required List<Widget> comments,
      }) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            CustomPaint(
              painter: CreateLine(root: true),
              child: Column(
                // root
                children: [
                  ListTile(
                    horizontalTitleGap: 0,
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(image),
                    ),
                    title: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 8),
                      child: Text(name),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 8),
                      child: Text(
                        subtitle,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    trailing: posteDate,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    // Content
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 240, 240),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                    child: content,
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: comments,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  commentRootTextfield(context),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        );
      }

      Widget commentTreeChild(
          BuildContext context, String image, List<Widget> commentReply,
          {bool last = false, double margin = 60}) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: margin, top: 15),
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: CreateLine(root: false, last: last),
            child: Column(
              // child 1
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 15,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(image),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 240, 240, 240),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10))),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'User Name',
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding:
                                        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                                    child: Text('20:18'),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              Text(
                                  """The expressions will be suitable for girls, guys, 
                        """),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                last ? commnetChildTextField(context) : commnetChildReplyButton(),
                Column(
                  children: commentReply,
                )
              ],
            ), // child root
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget commnetChildReplyButton() {
        return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 30,
            ),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 20,
              child: TextButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Text('Replay')),
            ));
      }

      Widget commnetChildTextField(BuildContext context) {
        return FittedBox(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 8, top: 16),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      'https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-69381991,width-650,imgsize-594328,,resizemode-4,quality-100/hacker-1.jpg'),
                  radius: 15,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231),
                      border: Border.all(width: 0.5),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                  child: TextField(
                    minLines: 1,
                    maxLines: 3,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Type your message...',
                      contentPadding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                      isDense: true,
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                    ),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget commentRootTextfield(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              top: BorderSide(width: 3, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231)),
              bottom:
                  BorderSide(width: 2, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231)),
            ),
          ),
          child: FittedBox(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: [
                IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.smile)),
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 231, 231, 231),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                    child: TextField(
                      minLines: 1,
                      maxLines: 3,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'Type your message...',
                        contentPadding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
                        isDense: true,
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                    width: 30,
                    child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.attach_file,
                          size: 25,
                        ))),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 40,
                  child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.mic,
                        size: 30,
                      )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class CreateLine extends CustomPainter {
      CreateLine({required this.root, this.last = false});

      final bool root;
      final bool last;
      @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        final p1 = size.topLeft(root ? Offset(35, 65) : Offset(15, 40));
        final p2 = root
            ? Offset(35, size.height - 53)
            : Offset(15, size.height - (last ? 40 : 0));
        final paint = Paint()
          ..color = Colors.black
          ..strokeWidth = 1;
        canvas.drawLine(p1, p2, paint);
        // TODO: implement paint
      }

      @override
      bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
        // TODO: implement shouldRepaint
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Output look like this now [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).